# fgets + dynamic malloc/realloc with a .txt as stdin

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, realloc

i'm trying to read lines of a file. txt, but without knowing the size of each lines...First I used the getline instruction (and works fine), but my teacher does not let me use that instruction, he says I can only use the fgets statement with malloc and realloc...

This is an input example, with variable line sizes:

```
[9.3,1.2,87.9]
[1.0,1.0]
[0.0,0.0,1.0]
```

As shown, each line defines a different vector with no size limit

Someone could help me implement this method?

Thank you very much.

NOTE: I forgot to mention, to compile the program I use these commands:

```
g++ -Wall-Wextra-Werror-pedantic main.c-o metbasicos.c metintermedios.c eda.exe

./eda.exe <eda.txt
```

Comment: Are the `[` and `]` actually part of the input file?, or just used here to illustrate the lines

Comment: Okay, working through some final wording, then will post code again.

Comment: So, you are asking SO people to write a function for you, which is a dynamic version of `fgets` and uses `realloc`? Sorry, but that kind of "write my code for me" question is explicitly offtopic for SO. To make it on-topic, show what you have tried, in other words show us your current version of the function, and tell how it works wrong.

Comment: But to give you a hint, a simple version (which is fairly good, thanks to default buffering) simply allocates a small buffer, keeps reading characters with `fgetc` until newline, and every time buffer is too small, it doubles the size of buffer with `realloc` (and, as optional last step after encountering newline, uses `realloc` to shrink the buffer to be exactly right size).

Comment: @hyde - I am interested in knowing about the implementation you are describing using `fgetc()` with incremental memory increases.  Would you mind expanding how you do that?

Comment: @ryyker well, my above comment is almost straight pseudocode... Just re-write it as actual pseudocode, add the few missing obvious statements (at least "store the char to the buffer" and "add string terminating `'\0'` char to the buffer"), then rewrite that as C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say do something similar to this

```
    while(fgets(buf, LEN, stdin)){
            z = strtok(buf, ",");
            *(*(matrix + i)) = atof(z);
            for(j = 1; j < col; ++j){
                    z = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    *(*(matrix + i) + j) = atof(z);
            }
            ++i;
    }
```

The only extra thing you would have to take care of is making sure that you strip the brackets off of the first and last element.

Of course, if you don't know the size of the final array, you might need something like this:

```
    struct data_t {
            int nval;               /* current number of values in array */
            int max;                /* allocated number of vlaues */
            char **words;           /* the data array */
    };

    enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

    ...
    while (fgets(buf, LEN, stdin)) {
            if (data->words == NULL)
                    data->words = malloc(sizeof(char *));
            else if (data->nval > data->max) {
                    data->words = realloc(data->words, GROW * data->max *sizeof(char *));
                    data->max = GROW * data->max;
            }
            z = strtok(buf, "\n");
            *(data->words + i) = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(z) + 1));
            strcpy(*(data->words + i), z);
            i++;
            data->nval++;           
    }
    data->nval--;
```

If you combine both of those while loops into a single one, you should be all set. The first one reads in floats, the second one is good for dynamically allocating space on the fly.

Comment: I think this is not what I need, I just want to know the size of each line and reserve space dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use multiple steps, then use one function to get the information you need to malloc memory.  (for example determine number of lines, and longest line)  This function will do that for you (given the file name and location)

[EDIT]  LineCount - This function will get you the ***number of lines***, *and* the ***longest line*** so you can dynamically allocate memory in `char **strings;` in which to read the lines of the input file.

```
int lineCount(char *file, int *nLines)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int cnt=0, longest=0, numLines=0;
    char c;
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    while ( (c = fgetc ( fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( c != '\n' ) 
        {
            cnt++;    
            if (cnt > longest) longest = cnt;
        }
        else 
        {
            numLines++;
            cnt= 0;
        }

    }
    *nLines = numLines+1;//add one more
    fclose(fp);
    return longest+1;
}
```

Here is the implementation to read the input file you provided, using the function above to get the *unknown* dimensions of the input file...

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "c:\\dev\\play\\in.txt" //put your own path here
#define DELIM "- ,:;//_*&[]\n"  //change this line as needed for search criteria

int lineCount(char *file, int *cnt);
void allocMemory(int numStrings, int max);
void freeMemory(int numStrings);

char **strings;

int main()
{
    int numLines, longest, cnt, i;
    FILE *fp;
    longest = lineCount(FILENAME, &numLines);

    char wordKeep[longest];
    allocMemory(numLines, longest);

    //read file into string arrays 
    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    cnt=0;
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<numLines;i++)
    {
        fgets(strings[i], longest, fp); 
    }
    fclose(fp);

    freeMemory(numLines);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int lineCount(char *file, int *nLines)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int cnt=0, longest=0, numLines=0;
    char c;
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    while ( (c = fgetc ( fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( c != '\n' ) 
        {
            cnt++;    
            if (cnt > longest) longest = cnt;
        }
        else 
        {
            numLines++;
            cnt= 0;
        }

    }
    *nLines = numLines+1;//add one more
    fclose(fp);
    return longest+1;
}

void allocMemory(int numStrings, int max)
{
    int i;
    // need number of lines by longest line for string containers
    strings = calloc(sizeof(char*)*(numStrings+1), sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      strings[i] = calloc(sizeof(char)*max + 1, sizeof(char));
    }
}

void freeMemory(int numStrings)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
        if(strings[i]) free(strings[i]);
    free(strings);  
}
```